# Django 3.0 URL parameters

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to create a link in a template based on the `request.GET.arg`
Lets say I enter the site which has url.com/?order=desc

What I'm trying to do is passing arg to url. I need the same link to be generated.

```
<a href="{% url 'index' order=request.get.order %}">Link</a>
```

It raises up this error:

```
Reverse for 'index' with keyword arguments '{'order': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']
```

Answer (score 0):

The *query string* is *not* part of the path. You encode this with:

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}?order={{ request.GET.order|urlencode }}">Link</a>
```

or if you want to pass the entire `request.GET` as *query string* again, you can work with:

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}">Link</a>
```

Comment: What if order doesn’t exist? Should i always check like this? {% if request.GET.order %}?

Comment: @Barrandov: then you can check it with `{% if 'order' in request.GET %}...{% endif %}`. But if you simply want to pass the entire `request.GET`, you can work with `?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}`.

Comment: Thank you! But I can't use this work around. My task is a bit more complicated. I'll have 2 args. Order (desc, acs) and Tag (list, could be infinite). So the final url could look like this: url.com/?tag=black&tag=white&tag=red&order=asc
i read this line with request.GET and render new proper urls.

I did that in flask and it worked perfectly. Maybe I need new mindset for Django :)